# Error when using playwright (robotframework)

Tags: automation, robotframework, playwright

When I run a .robot file that uses the browser library the test fails with this error in the logs

```html
Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'Browser' failed: Could not connect to the playwright process at port 52161
```

(I have already installed playwright with this command "npx playwright install" and run "rfbrowser init")

I found out that I need to install a node version> 12 so I installed  the version 16.13.0

I run again "rfbrowser int"

When I execute the .robot file the test fails with this error

TimeoutError: browserType.launch: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
 /mnt/c/Users/skhalil/workspace2/rf_training/ve_rftr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Browser/wrapper/node_modules/playwright-core/.local-browsers/chromium-930007/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-Y7xOid --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
 pid=5743

[pid=5743][err] [5743:5743:1128/225155.804904:FATAL:ozone_platform_x11.cc(238)] Check failed: x11::Connection::Get()->Ready(). Missing X server or $DISPL...
[ Message content over the limit has been removed. ]

..ch-11" = "--disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,Globa"

[pid=5743][err]   "switch-10" = "--disable-extensions"

[pid=5743][err]   "switch-9" = "--disable-dev-shm-usage"

[pid=5743][err]   "switch-8" = "--disable-default-apps"

[pid=5743][err]   "switch-7" = "--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages"

[pid=5743][err]   "switch-6" = "--disable-client-side-phishing-detection"

[pid=5743][err]   "switch-5" = "--disable-breakpad"

[pid=5743][err]   "switch-4" = "--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows"

[pid=5743][err]   "switch-3" = "--disable-background-timer-throttling"

[pid=5743][err]   "switch-2" = "--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess"

[pid=5743][err]   "switch-1" = "--disable-background-networking"

[pid=5743][err]   "num-switches" = "30"

[pid=5743][err]   "osarch" = "x86_64"

[pid=5743][err]   "pid" = "5743"

[pid=5743][err]   "ptype" = "browser"

[pid=5743][err]

[pid=5743][err] [1128/225218.444392:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu

Comment: Do you install the NodeJs? Check installation step on the official site.  https://robotframework-browser.org/#installation

Comment: @Lomomo usage of npx would indicate that there is some node version present ..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first error you stated:

```
Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'Browser' failed: Could not connect to the playwright process at port
```

I get this when I have the environmental variables https_proxy and/or http_proxy (case insensitive) set. Just unset them and it should work. (I always set those vars only temporarily for my session when I need to install new packages behind company proxy)

Regarding the second error:

```
TimeoutError: browserType.launch:...
```

In my company we started to get this suddenly a few months back, we could not find the cause for it and it affected windows users only, on mac it still worked (no linux users among us tho). The chrome.exe from the browser lib just could not be opened any more, not even manually - there is no error it just simply won't launch. Firefox would still work, however. Since we use chromium baseds browser in our company, we did not want firefox thus we solved this by setting the 'channel' arg to use installed stock browser rather then the one from Browser lib like this:

```
Suite Setup    New Browser    channel=chrome
```

...or channel=edge if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you, listener issue fixed for me after removing https_proxy and/or http_proxy